# Confused about this annuity problem involving yearly payment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Usually in this type of problem I can solve using log but since there is negative it seems like it can go on forever.

A fund of $20,000$ earns an annual effective interest of $0.09%$ and pays $1000$ once a year at the end of the year. The question asks how many payments and what is the value after the final payment.

So can anyone help me to see what I am missing? Is it a perpetuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick calculation, in the first year it earns $9\%$ of $\$20,000.00$, which means it earned $\$1,800$. So the net earnings are $\$800$.

Since you ended up with more than you had, then it will continue to earn more and more (you can prove it more formally by induction), so there's no "final" payment, in that the fund will eventually run out.

Maybe you were missing out on a fixed end year (like, 10 years from now)?